# Can I use PHP to manipulate Internet Explorer via COM?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, com

I wanted to ask if using COM to press buttons and enter in fields in Internet Explorer is possible through PHP coding.

I researched it a bit and it seems like something like that exists but how is it possible if PHP is server sided?

In AHK, I would do this:

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

and after the COM documents in php.net

I would do this?

```
$obj = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

I'm a bit confused to how this works , so iIwould love to understand how PHP and COM work together because in AHK it opens Internet Explorer. I doubt a website can do that for you... or can it?

Answer (score 1):

Not using COM. You're much better off using JS on the client to manipulate the DOM.

In particular, this bit of code:

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

creates an instance of Internet Explorer *on the server*, not the client.

To have the server manipulate the client DOM, you're going to need some sort of back-channel (web request) and have the client send up requests and process changes.

Comment: So you can use javascript to enter fields and press buttons ETC?

Comment: ill take a look at DOM

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use PHP and COM to do this as they both work on the Server, you are trying to do things on the client.

Try javascript.